# Further Summarize Pivot Table Results (Average)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This seems like something that should be so simple, but I can't figure it out this morning.  I've even had my coffee.  I am returning four fields from a WebFOCUS query:  SHIPWEEK, Ship Date, Part Numberand Quantity (QTY).  I set up the query so that it pulls 365 days of records when the workbook opens.  I have then summarized the data into a Pivot Table.  The Pivot Table simply shows SHIPWEEK as a row with two VALUES:  Count of QTY and Sum of QTY.  This all works fine.

What I want beyond this, however, is to calculate for the range of the returned results the average weekly count and standard deviation.  I can do this simply by using the AVERAGE() and STDEV() functions and pointing to the two VALUES ranges in the Pivot Table.  That will work once.  But I'd like to not have to manually adjust the range for these formulas each time I run the query.  Theoretically, there will be the same number of weeks in 365 days of data, but that may not always be the case.  If the number of rows in the Pivot Table changes, then it might skew my results.

Surely there is a way to do this in the Pivot Table itself?  Pivot Table offers a "Grand Total" option, which will sum all of the records, but I don't know how to do the equivalent of "Grand Total" for average or Standard Deviation.

If not in the Pivot Table, then dynamically outside of the Pivot Table without requiring manual range updates each time?

Comment: How does your dataset look like? What are you running *stdev* and *avg* calculations for?

Comment: Sorry.  I tried to insert a screen shot, but apparently I'm not allowed to do that on this site until I've contributed enough.  The dataset is four fields:  Ship Week (Date field returns the date of the Friday of the ship date), Ship Date, Part Number, and Quantity shipped.  I'm not sure how to elaborate on that more, but if you still have questions I'll be glad to try to answer them.  After all, you're helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I think (though I'm not sure) that this answers your question.  In the PivotTable Builder, select the value you are trying to calculate, and click on the detail button (so in the image below, the little "i" next to the appropriate item in "values".  Then select the function you want instead.

[image]

Comment: This isn't what I'm after.  This is basically the same technique I used to create 'Count' and 'Sum' Values fields in the Pivot Table I already have.  Doing this will give me Standard Devation/Average calculations for each week.  What I'm trying to do is get a weekly average/standard deviation for the 52 week period.  In other words, in the last year, how many transactions are performed in an average week?  Is that clearer?